# javamail transport send requests attachment multiple times

Tags: jakarta-mail

I currently have a fully functional email notification system. It is all working correctly, but have noticed that one of the inline images, which is attached to the email via a rest service, is being requested three times.

It appears to be happening once transport.send is invoked. I'm assuming that when javamail goes to send email, it then calls for all inline images referenced and generates the base64 image and places it in the outgoing email.

My question is... 
Is the above assumptions correct and why would it be calling the service multiple times when it has been verified in the raw email that it contains the image only once.

Below is a copy of the raw email with addresses changed, base64 images,  text/plain and text/html versions removed.

### Raw email

```
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 20:40:04 -0800 (PST)
From: something.news.noreply@something.org
To: user.email@something.org
Message-ID: <56557433.31456461613977.JavaMail.something.news.noreply@something.orgh>
Subject: Business News for 02/26/2016
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_6_670038123.1456461604268"
X-Priority: 3

------=_Part_6_670038123.1456461604268
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

TEXT VERSION OF EMAIL


------=_Part_6_670038123.1456461604268
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
    boundary="----=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268"

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

HTML VERSION OF EMAIL

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="840da574-a395-4fb8-8f33-bcbb1837220e?t=1452039853427"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@9dc060f2-84ec-4344-8871-68d4e4885b70_840da574-a395-4fb8-8f33-bcbb1837220e?t=1452039853427>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="840da574-a395-4fb8-8f33-bcbb1837220e?t=1452039853427"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="21ae1010-9675-4daa-8ac8-659052b943e8?t=1450724912940"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@17ab1018-2bc5-44f5-9934-fb7b0f1a860b_21ae1010-9675-4daa-8ac8-659052b943e8?t=1450724912940>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="21ae1010-9675-4daa-8ac8-659052b943e8?t=1450724912940"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="a96af9b6-9093-4086-bf91-e5677bef533f?t=1450966405365"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@15a682c9-95e8-42ee-880b-f52a47396341_a96af9b6-9093-4086-bf91-e5677bef533f?t=1450966405365>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="a96af9b6-9093-4086-bf91-e5677bef533f?t=1450966405365"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="25caf361-80a9-44c2-9ae6-97c19709becf?t=1450966427231"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@2e9839ae-9c10-4c8f-9c4a-bc9e1a934fc3_25caf361-80a9-44c2-9ae6-97c19709becf?t=1450966427231>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="25caf361-80a9-44c2-9ae6-97c19709becf?t=1450966427231"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; name=upChart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@6ca90a68-1d24-4414-ac8a-8c84b50bb663_upChart>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=upChart

BASE 64 IMAGE
THIS IS THE IMAGE THAT IS RETRIEVED VIA A WEB SERVICE CALL. IT CREATES A CHART
IMAGE THAT GET ATTACHED TO EMAIL.

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="10739ce0-c979-4e47-8cee-666304b9a92e?t=1451426510519"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@14227419-3db7-444b-a704-7abaccd1e380_10739ce0-c979-4e47-8cee-666304b9a92e?t=1451426510519>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="10739ce0-c979-4e47-8cee-666304b9a92e?t=1451426510519"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268
Content-Type: image/png; 
    name="995344fa-765f-4a27-848c-d36d26c593f3?t=1451426553685"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <@f17f0535-a2a3-47a8-aca4-9ed883542de8_995344fa-765f-4a27-848c-d36d26c593f3?t=1451426553685>
Content-Disposition: inline; 
    filename="995344fa-765f-4a27-848c-d36d26c593f3?t=1451426553685"

BASE 64 IMAGE

------=_Part_7_2073972040.1456461604268--

------=_Part_6_670038123.1456461604268--
```

I have added I believe the relevant code. The code starts with what it started out like and then two changes I made based on the suggestion.

Started as:

```
try {
    //  Get a REST client so we can call the Highcharts service.
        hcClient = new RestClient(hcServer, hcResource);

    //  Create a client response object.
        ClientResponse cr = null;

    //  Initialize tries counter and loop a maximum of 3 tries
    //  if highcharts export server doesn't respond with a 200.
        int tries = 0;
        do {
            //  Increase tries count.
                tries++;

            //  Call the service and place response data into our data object.
                cr = hcClient.getWebResource().post(ClientResponse.class, params);

            //  Pull the response status from client.
                upChartRespStatus = cr.getStatus();

            //  Determine if we received a 200 code or not.
                if(upChartRespStatus == 200) {
                    //  Obtain entity and build response.
                        response = Response
                            .ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(cr.getEntity(cbChart.getClass())))
                            .build();
                } else {
                    //    Log warning that chart was not received, what the response
                    //    status was and what try we are on.
                          logger.warn("Unable to get requested chart, response code was "+upChartRespStatus+".");
                          logger.warn("Reattempting to get chart. The current count of retries is: "+tries);
                }
        } while (tries <= 3 && upChartRespStatus != 200);
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    hcClient.destroy();
}
```

I thought maybe I would try sending a base64 encoded image. I didn't even get the image in the email doing this.

```
        //  Determine if we received a 200 code or not.
            if(upChartRespStatus == 200) {
                //  Get entity from client request.
                    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(cr.getEntity(cbChart.getClass()));
                    String b64Image = new String(Base64.encode(read(bais)));

                //  Obtain entity and build response.
                    response = Response
                        .ok(b64Image)
                        .header("Content-Type", "image/png")
                        .header("Content-Length", b64Image.length())
                        .header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "BASE64")
                        .build();
            } else {
                //    Log warning that chart was not received, what the response
                //    status was and what try we are on.
                      logger.warn("Unable to get requested chart, response code was "+upChartRespStatus+".");
                      logger.warn("Reattempting to get chart. The current count of retries is: "+tries);
            }
```

My last attempt was going back to binary, but making sure that the headers were all in place. This last attempt did yield the chart image in the email, but still in all cases the transport.send is still calling the service three times before it actually sends.

```
        //  Determine if we received a 200 code or not.
            if(upChartRespStatus == 200) {
                //  Get entity from client request.
                    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(cr.getEntity(cbChart.getClass()));

                //  Obtain entity and build response.
                    response = Response
                        .ok(bais)
                        .header("Content-Type", "image/png")
                        .header("Content-Length", bais.available())
                        .header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "BINARY")
                        .build();
            } else {
                //    Log warning that chart was not received, what the response
                //    status was and what try we are on.
                      logger.warn("Unable to get requested chart, response code was "+upChartRespStatus+".");
                      logger.warn("Reattempting to get chart. The current count of retries is: "+tries);
            }
```

Okay. So I got some success. Instead of setting headers at the service, I think that was to late. I took a look at the code that creates the email and specifically when the image gets added to its part. I've added what the code was and what I changed. By doing this, it is now only calling the service twice instead of three times.

```
private void addImagesInline(Multipart parent, List<URL> embeded, HashMap<String,String> cids) throws MessagingException {
    if (embeded != null) {
        for (URL img : embeded) {
            final MimeBodyPart htmlPartImg = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource htmlPartImgDs = new URLDataSource(img);
            htmlPartImg.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(htmlPartImgDs));
            String fileName = img.getFile();
            fileName = getFileName(fileName);
            String newFileName = cids.get(fileName);
            boolean imageNotReferencedInHtml = newFileName == null;
            if (imageNotReferencedInHtml) continue;
            htmlPartImg.setHeader("Content-ID", "<"+newFileName+">");
            htmlPartImg.setDisposition(BodyPart.INLINE);
            htmlPartImg.setFileName(fileName);
            parent.addBodyPart(htmlPartImg);
        }
    }
}
```

I added these to lines of code.

```
        htmlPartImg.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
        htmlPartImg.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "BASE64");
```

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the image to be requested twice.  JavaMail will read the image once to determine what encoding is appropriate, based on the content of the image data.  It will then read it again to encode it and include it in the message.

You can read the image yourself and save it locally to avoid multiple requests, or you can tell JavaMail what encoding to use by setting the Content-Transfer-Encoding header for the part; that way it won't have to guess what to use.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't seem to make any difference. I edited my question with what I believe is the relevant code. The problem is I really don't want it calling the service three times for each of the thousands of subscribers we have.

Comment: So it did help, but the service is still being called twice. Is there anything else I could add? Is it by chance content-length? The problem there is that I don't know the length of the image until it passes through the service.

Comment: I don't know why it's being called twice.  Try setting a breakpoint in the client at URLDataSource.getInputStream and see who's calling it.